# TypeScript: Type a function that can call any function that exists on an interface

Tags: typescript

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
interface Functions {
  onChange: (value: number) => boolean;
  onMenuOpen: () => number;
}
const functions: Functions = {
  onChange: (value: number) => {
    return true;
  },
  onMenuOpen: () => {
    return 5;
  }
}

function call<K extends keyof Functions>(key: K,  ...args: Parameters<Functions[K]>): ReturnType<Functions[K]> {
  return functions[key](...args);
}

const test: boolean = call('onChange', 5);
const test2: number = call('onMenuOpen');
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIFcQLMA9iAZ2QG8BYAKGWXwGEALOEAcwgC5kAKANzgBt02yEOgC2AI2gBKZAF4AfMjG5cvCIwDcFKvgCyEYQHkADvvYdp8oaIlRN5AL4UE+AmGQxM2PIXYYsOF1kSLWoQekYWMx5+QWFxKVkFMkoqZCgIMHQoEGQwKAE7KnsAGhDdfXRjU04LJJCqdMzs5ABWQuRHBwoKD39vZAQ+XgAeAGlkCAAPSBAAEyIAawgAT1wYNE8AwjkOJeX2UeKqADpTuCgmAnYABXO4EQzoAmG-LxcAbVGAXTlJdgAlDJZEAAFWWJhem28BE+P2CKUawPcUI+ey+HFOx3Ol0kdk6ThcbkgrnYShUahyMgGQw4AHJaAxmBBaUcWriCYQiRBXAAmdhxGxBQa8Xh08qGEwgWns8hAA)

It gives two errors:

1. `Type 'number | boolean' is not assignable to type 'ReturnType<Functions[K]>'. Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'ReturnType<Functions[K]>'.`
2. `Expected 1 arguments, but got 0 or more.`

Is there a way to type this without casting?

Comment: Yeah, the compiler unfortunately can't follow the generic correlation between `functions[key]` and `args`.  You'll need some type safety loosening either with type assertions or `any` or something.  Maybe like [this](https://tsplay.dev/ewek1m) (that uses `any` as the constraint for the input and return types of the `F` parameter)?  See [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) where I have been maintaining a list of these questions (without much hope of anything being done about it, I'm afraid)

Comment: Thanks, you're the best!